# How to get authProvider for OneNote API

Tags: onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I'm using MS.Graph and trying to get a list of my OneNote Notebooks.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(clientId)
.WithTenantId(tenantID)
.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
.Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var notebooks = await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Notebooks
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

I can get the clientID, but where/how to I get the tenantID and clientSecret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Microsoft.Graph.Auth (Pre-Release) from NuGet.  That fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get more info through this reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider